# Posting parameters and array in header in CURL using PHP

Tags: php, curl

i am facing an issue i just need to send an array in header and some parameters in body but when i add

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Token:'.$token));
```

this line sends token but parameters array get empty but when i just remove the line, parameters successfully send  but token is missing

here is the code have look:

```
      $data = array(

        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'city' => $_POST['city'],
        'mobileNo' => $_POST['mobileNo'],
      );

      $params = http_build_query($data);
      $curl = curl_init('URL');
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
      array('Token:'.$token));
      $result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: @FrankerZ still same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you overwrite headers and because of that missing content type header. You must add that header to your headers array:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
'Token: '.$token,
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Content-Length: '.strlen($params)
));
```

edit: I've updated post to the working solution

Comment: I have added the  
'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
in my code  but still parameters  are empty

Comment: Did you remove line I've put in PS section?

Comment: Ok, one more try: bring back line I told to remove, set Content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and add another header: `'Content-Length: '.strlen($params)`

Comment: Error is resolved thank you very much for helping i was stuck in this problem from last 2 days <3

Comment: So last change I said was the solution?

Comment: Cool. I've updated my post to set there working solution. Please, set my post/answer as a solving problem answer to let others that problem is solved already.